# What should I set my advanced 802.11n Wireless LAN Card Properties?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-vista

My operating system is Windows Vista Home Premium, and obtians Internet through Wi-Fi.

I want to use the Internet mostly for research and be able to watch a YouTube video now and then. No major streaming or gaming.

What should I set my advanced 802.11n Wireless LAN Card Properties to? Specifically for these items:

Property: 
Adhoc support 802.11n 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
Frame Aggregation 
Value: (currently: Enable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
IEEE802.11h 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
Multimedia/Gaming Environment 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
Radio On/Off 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
RDG 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
TX Burst 
Value: (currently: Enable) Enable or disable?

Property: 
WMM Capable 
Value: (currently: Disable) Enable or disable?

[image]

I was trying to get the computer to receive Wi-Fi signals, and I looked in the wrong place messing up the default settings of the advanced Wireless LAN Card properties. Now I am just trying to set the properties to their default state, or a state best suited for my use. Thanks!

Comment: If you want default settings, just uninstall the wireless network adapter from Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`) and press the **Scan for hardware changes** button.

Comment: Play with Radio On/Off first, and Power Saving Mode second.  Set Country Region to your country.  And next time, take a screenshot before changing it :)